# Canon printer does not print RAW when using fsockopen() to connect to printer on network

Tags: php, printing, raw

I have a Canon iSensys MF217w that is connected to a public IP address. I need to be able to print to this printer directly from our website from which we print orders.

This is the code that I use:

```
$outputString = "Hello World!";
$Ip = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$port = "9100";
  $fp = fsockopen($Ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 15);
if (!$fp) {
  echo json_encode("$errstr ($errno)<br />\n");
} else {
  try {
    $kk=fwrite($fp, $outputString, strlen($outputString));
    fclose($fp);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode('Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n");
  } 
}
```

This code works perfectly fine to any other printer except the Canon printer.

fsockopen() is successfull as I don't receive any errors but the printer does not print the print job.

Answer (score 1):

From what I could gather is that the printer I am trying to connect to only supports UFRII and I need a printer that supports PostScript to be able to print RAW.